# cbind specific columns from multiple csv files

Tags: r, csv, subset

I have multiple of these CSV files with the same headers

[image]

I am trying to cbind the log2FoldChange and padj columns from all of my CSV into one data frame. I want the end result to look like this

[image]

With the specific columns appended together.

My code so far

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
res1 <- do.call(cbind, lapply(files,read.csv, header = T))
pos <- grep("log2FoldChange|padj", names(res1))
dataset <- res1[, pos]
```

But the columns (log2FoldChange, padj) in my dataset at the end don't match the values of the CSV progenitors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge:

```
f1 <- read.csv("file1.csv")
f2 <- read.csv("file2.csv")
dataset <- merge(f1, f2, by.x = "row.names", by.y = "row.names")
```